# Maven plugin that generates openapi3 json from swagger 2 annotations

Tags: java, maven, swagger, maven-plugin, swagger-maven-plugin

Project uses annotations from swagger 2, from this package:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

And then this to generate swagger json:

```
          ...  <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>...
```

But that plugin cannot generate json for openapi 3. Is there any maven plugin that can generate openapi 3 json using annotations from aforementioned package?

Comment: There's [openapi-tools/swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openapi-tools/swagger-maven-plugin) which is "heavily inspired by that" refering to the plugin you have tried to use already, have you given that a try yet? It supports OpenAPI 3.0 and is available on Maven Central.

Comment: I've been searching for something like that, thanks, I'll give it a try.